# How to filter a ListView output based on ID from current URL

Tags: python, django, django-urls

My project a shopping list. I have two models: ShoppingList and ShoppingItem like this:

models.py

```
class ShoppingItem (Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    count = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    list = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='shopping_items')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('ListDetails/<int:pk>', views.ListDetailUpdateView.as_view(), name='listdetailupdate'),
]
```

views.py

```
class ListDetailUpdateView(ListView):
    model = ShoppingItem
    template_name = 'xlist_app/ListDetailUpdateView.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    queryset = ShoppingItem.objects.filter(list = XXXX)
```

I need function that return part of url but inside ListView(where"XXXX")

My idea is to cut last part of url (for example when i enter list number 2 i have address `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ListDetails/2`) and replace "XXXX" with such a function.

In my mind it should look like:

```
queryset = ShoppingItem.objects.filter(list = int(request.path.split('/')[-1])
```

if there is a better way to do that i will aprreciate all sugestions

Comment: Do you have any urlpatterns defined for this view?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I have this:
path('ListDetails/<int:pk>', views.ListDetailUpdateView.as_view(), name='listdetailupdate'),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that

```
class ListDetailUpdateView(ListView):
    model = ShoppingItem
    template_name = 'xlist_app/ListDetailUpdateView.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
       return ShoppingItem.objects.filter(list=self.request.resolver_match.kwargs['pk'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `get_queryset` method is a way to go.

Calling `super()` gets the queryset returned by the parent method. Filtering on it should work just fine.
`pk` matched by url pattern will be available in `self.kwargs`.

```
class ListDetailUpdateView(ListView):
    model = ShoppingItem
    template_name = 'xlist_app/ListDetailUpdateView.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ListDetailUpdateView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(list=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

I'd also consider changing `list` field name to `shopping_list` or similar, as it shadows the [built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) `list()` function.